# Run JavaFX On Windows Mobile

Tags: javafx, windows-mobile

I've a Samsung Omnia i900 that runs Windows Mobile OS. Believe it or not, but nowhere on the Internet can I find information on running a JavaFX application on it. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, JavaFX Mobile hasn't been released. Some of the pre-release tools worked on Windows Mobile (judging by some blog posts) but that support was dropped from the 1.0 release.

JavaFX 1.1 is meant to have Windows Mobile support, but it looks like that's on the development side rather than on real devices - the fact that there's a mobile *emulator* as one of the key features for JavaFX 1.1 is quite telling.

According to [the FAQ](http://www.javafx.com/faq/#2.4):

> 2.4 How can consumers get JavaFX on their handsets?
>
> Sun is working with Mobile Device
>   Manufacturers and Mobile Operators to
>   enable out of the box support for
>   JavaFX content by preloading the
>   JavaFX Mobile runtime with their
>   devices

That doesn't exactly sound encouraging for being able to get it on your handset right now. I may be missing something, but I certainly couldn't find anything to download...

Answer (score 3):

JavaFX Mobile is now available in Early Access for Windows Mobile devices. You can download the binary from [javafx.com](http://javafx.com/downloads/all.jsp).